# Move a set of N-rows to another column in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, copy, rows

Is it possible to instead of copying a set of N-rows from a column to another column, can i possibly move it.

This is my code to 'copy' the rows over to another column.

```
numberofPdbs(1:235,2) = numberofPdbs(236:end,1);
```

I need to find a way to move them to another column.

Please advise.

Comment: If my answer does not address your case, could you elaborate on what you mean by "move" (desired behavior, impact on matrix size, other columns)?

Answer (score 1):

Moving a column:

```
%# Columns before destination are shifted back.
%# Matrix size unchanged.
data = rand(100);
desiredCol = 5;
destinationCol = 15;
data = [ data(:,1:desiredCol-1) ...
         data(:,desiredCol+1:destinationCol) ...
         data(:,desiredCol) ...
         data(:,destinationCol+1:end) ];
```

Swapping two columns:

```
%# Matrix size unchanged.
temp = data(:,destinationCol);
data(:,destinationCol) = data(:,desiredCol);
data(:,desiredCol) = temp;
```

Move with overwrite:

```
%# Destination is not preserved.
%# Matrix size decreases by 1.
data(:,destinationCol) = data(:,desiredCol);
data(:,desiredCol) = [];
```