# Shifting repeating rows to a new column in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I am working with a n x 1 matrix, A, that has repeating values inside it:

```
A = [0;1;2;3;4;   0;1;2;3;4;   0;1;2;3;4;    0;1;2;3;4]
```

which correspond to an n x 1 matrix of B values:

```
B = [2;4;6;8;10;  3;5;7;9;11;  4;6;8;10;12;  5;7;9;11;13]
```

I am attempting to produce a generalised code to place each repetition into a separate column and store it into Aa and Bb, e.g.:

```
Aa = [0  0  0  0     Bb = [2  3  4  5
      1  1  1  1           4  5  6  7
      2  2  2  2           6  7  8  9
      3  3  3  3           8  9  10 11
      4  4  4  4]          10 11 12 13]
```

Essentially, each repetition from A and B needs to be copied into the next column and then deleted from the first column

[image: Visual description of matrix row shifting to columns (paint)]

So far I have managed to identify how many repetitions there are and copy the entire column over to the next column and then the next for the amount of repetitions there are but my method doesn't shift the matrix rows to columns as such.

```
clc;clf;close all
A = [0;1;2;3;4;0;1;2;3;4;0;1;2;3;4;0;1;2;3;4];
B = [2;4;6;8;10;3;5;7;9;11;4;6;8;10;12;5;7;9;11;13];

desiredCol = 1; %next column to go to
destinationCol = 0; %column to start on
n = length(A);
for i = 2:1:n-1
 if A == 0;
   A = [ A(:, 1:destinationCol)...
         A(:, desiredCol+1:destinationCol)...
         A(:, desiredCol)...
         A(:, destinationCol+1:end) ];
 end
end
```

A = [...] retrieved from [Move a set of N-rows to another column in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405266/move-a-set-of-n-rows-to-another-column-in-matlab)

Any hints would be much appreciated. If you need further explanation, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few questions one needs to ask before answering you: (1) Will `A` **guarantee** to be repeating? For example, what if `A = [0 1 2 3 0 3 2 1];`? (2) If `A` is guaranteed to be repeating, do you know **the period**?  For example, we can see here that the period is 5 samples. Is this known before hand, or do you have to calculate this yourself? If you know the periodicity, your answer is simply `Aa = reshape(A,T,[]); Bb = reshape(B,T,[]);` where `T` is the period. (3) Does `A` only have **unique** elements?  What happens if `A = [1 1 1 1];`? Is the period between patterns 1, 2, or 4?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A is guaranteed to be repeating but the period will be different. Although, this can be easily calculated by "n = length(A); T=n/An" where An is the number of repetitions. A will only have unique elements that are equidistant. Considering all of this I will give your reshape command a try and let you know! You've given me a lot to think about when asking questions on stackoverflow, so thank you!

Comment: :). Asking questions here on StackOverflow requires more of an art and practice compared to answering questions.  I find that with questions, I have to keep coming back and putting in more details because there are certain scenarios that I didn't consider when posing the question.  However with answers, I rarely have to edit because I clearly know what I'm going to write about.  Don't worry, you're not the only one that feels this way... and do let me know how it goes with `reshape`.  If it does work, allow me to write an official answer. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, the more questions I ask the more I learn about what to think of with my own work. Sometimes I solve the answer just by asking myself the right questions haha. I will have to let you know tomorrow as I don't have Matlab on this PC. Thanks again.

Comment: This works perfectly ray. Thanks a lot for a very simplistic answer. I wish I knew about this command a couple of days ago :') If you write an official answer then it will be marked as the Answer!

Comment: I certainly will write one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given our discussion in the comments, all you need is to use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) which converts a matrix of known dimensions into an output matrix with specified dimensions provided that the number of elements match.  You wish to transform a vector which has a set amount of repeating patterns into a matrix where each column has one of these repeating instances.  `reshape` creates a matrix in column-major order where values are sampled column-wise and the matrix is populated this way.  This is perfect for your situation.

Assuming that you already know how many "repeats" you're expecting, we call this `An`, you simply need to reshape your vector so that it has `T = n / An` rows where `n` is the length of the vector.  Something like this will work.

```
n = numel(A); T = n / An;
Aa = reshape(A, T, []); 
Bb = reshape(B, T, []);
```

The third parameter has empty braces and this tells MATLAB to infer how many columns there will be given that there are `T` rows.  Technically, this would simply be `An` columns but it's nice to show you how flexible MATLAB can be.

Answer (score 2):

If you say you already know the repeated subvector, and the number of times it repeats then it is relatively straight forward:

First make your new `A` matrix with the [`repmat`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function.
Then remap your `B` vector to the same size as you new `A` matrix

```
% Given that you already have the repeated subvector Asub, and the number
% of times it repeats; An:


Asub = [0;1;2;3;4];
An = 4;
lengthAsub = length(Asub);

Anew = repmat(Asub, [1,An]);

% If you can assume that the number of elements in B is equal to the number
% of elements in A:

numberColumns = size(Anew, 2);

newB = zeros(size(Anew));
for i = 1:numberColumns
    indexStart = (i-1) * lengthAsub + 1;
    indexEnd = indexStart + An;
    newB(:,i) = B(indexStart:indexEnd);
end
```

If you don't know what is in your original `A` vector, but you do know it is repetitive, if you assume that the pattern has no repeats you can use the [`find`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function to find when the first element is repeated:

```
lengthAsub = find(A(2:end) == A(1), 1);
Asub = A(1:lengthAsub);
An = length(A) / lengthAsub
```

Hopefully this fits in with your data: the only reason it would not is if your subvector within `A` is a pattern which does not have unique numbers, such as:

```
A = [0;1;2;3;2;1;0;   0;1;2;3;2;1;0;   0;1;2;3;2;1;0;   0;1;2;3;2;1;0;]
```

It is worth noting that from the above intuitively you would have `lengthAsub = find(A(2:end) == A(1), 1) - 1;`, But this is not necessary because you are already effectively taking the one off by only looking in the matrix `A(2:end)`.